# Running threads in background and passing data to thread as needed

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a requirement to run a thread in background in java and may need to pass some information to the thread before it starts doing its actual function.

How to implement this?

Secondly, is it possible to start a thread which does further operation and exit from request context. Please note that I have to implement in a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to start a thread which does further operation and exit from request context. Please note that I have to implement in a web application.

You can use an ExecutorService to pass any number of tasks to and shutdown when you have finished with it.

Answer (score 2):

An example to answer your first question:

```
class NewThread extends Thread
{
    public String someInformation;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(someInformation);
    }
}

public class YourClass
{
    public void startANewThread()
    {
        NewThread newThread = new NewThread();
        newThread.someInformation = "hello";
        newThread.start();
    }
}
```

As for your second question: This code should run in a web application, but you must be extremely careful to make sure, that these background Threads will finish at some point, or else that would be a nice little memory leak.

Please note, that if you want to share information when both Threads are running, you need to synchronize information access.

Depending on what the background Thread does it might make sense to use a framework like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code, with two threads, where one thread will run in background and another thread will start executing the task. And here you can set a return type as well unlike thread.run() method.

```
FutureTask<Response> future = new FutureTask<>(newCallable<Response>() {
    public yourreturntype call() {
        doSomething(Thread1);
    }
});

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(future); 
doSomethingelse(Thread2)
//This thread doesnot wait for thread1 to complete
```

Comment: Consider explaining your answer a bit more - just a block of code will often not help to really understand whats going on and why it should be done this way.

Comment: Hi LionC , Thanks, Chk it now.